# Get all keys from ruby hash also where value is array with hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

If I have a `Hash` such as with subhashes, which are nested in arrays of the value of a `Hash`:

```
{"school" => "School name", "teachers" => [{"name" => "Schmith", "age" => 34},{"name" => "McRight", "age" => 51}]}


def get_keys(hash)
    (hash.keys + hash.values.grep(Hash){|sub_hash| get_keys(sub_hash)}).flatten
end
```

With the previous function I can get only `["school","teachers"]`, but I need also the keys of the hashes, which are in the array of the "teachers" value: `["school","teachers","name","age","name","age"]`

Preferable I would like to eliminate duplications in the result to have: `["school","teachers","name","age"]`

Comment: `grep(Hash)` finds hashes, but `[{"name" => "Schmith" ...` is an array.

Comment: I know, but I cannot figure out how to get also the keys of the hashes, which are in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_keys(object)
  if object.is_a? Hash
    (object.keys + get_keys(object.values)).flatten.uniq
  elsif object.is_a? Array 
    object.collect{|value| get_keys value}
  else
    []
  end
end
```

I think this is quite clear, and you can nest as much as you want.
If the object is not an array or hash, then there are no keys.
If it's an array, it will look for the keys that could be in all the elements
And if it's a hash, it will return its keys, plus the keys of the hashes that could be on the values of the hash. Then you apply `flatten` to remove possible empty arrays, and `uniq` to remove duplicate values.

With arrays, it will get the keys that could be inside of the

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to do something like this and when the value is an Array, call the same function recursively for each object in the array.

```
hash = {"school" => "School name", "teachers" => [{"name" => "Schmith", "age" => 34},{"name" => "McRight", "age" => 51}]}

def get_keys(hash)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), arr|
    arr << k
    if v.is_a? Array
      arr << v.map { |hash2| get_keys(hash2) }.uniq
    end
  end
end

puts get_keys(hash)
=> ["school", "teachers", "name", "age"]
```